# Grails 3 src/main/webapp loading app.js file

Tags: angularjs, grails, asset-pipeline, grails3

So I'm trying to get a simple Grails 3 and Angular app working. Upon firing up locally, I would expect my `app.js` file to get loaded and then load my `index.html`.

I'm not entirely sure how the `index/main gsps` work, but my understanding is that, using `asset-pipeline`, it should direct to my `app.js` under `src/main/webapp/js` and `$routeProvider` will handle the rest. But it's never redirecting to my `app.js`. It appears to still be searching for files within the `grails-app/assets` folder.

Here is my `index.gsp`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<asset:javascript src="app.js"/>
</head>
<body>

<asset:javascript src="app.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

`main.gsp`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>

<p>Here</p>

<asset:javascript src="../../../src/main/webapp/js/app.js"/>

<g:layoutHead/>
</head>
<body>

<g:layoutBody/>

<asset:javascript src="../../../src/main/webapp/js/app.js"/>
```

Here is my `context-path` from `application.yml`

```
server:
   contextPath: '/item-upload'
```

My `app.js` is located under `src/main/webapp/js`. This is the replacement directory for `webapp` in Grails 3. So I'm putting my js, html, and css files there.

`App.js`:

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular.module('common.initSideNavPanel', []);

var ngModule = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'item-upload'
]);

// Configure routing
ngModule.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'html/index.html', controller: 'UploadCtrl', pageName: 'upload'});

}]);

}(window.angular));
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to give the full path to asset,<asset:javascript src="app.js"/> should work, isn't it?

Comment: @Prakash I tried that as well, and it still searched in assets folder.

Comment: asset pipeline by default searches the resources under asset folder. Why don't you just copy the files to asset folder instead. Then it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Directory Structure is important.

Asset pipeline plugin requires the resources to be at certain directories, unless you are taking control of specifying the asset pipeline configuration in `build.gradle` file.

From [documentation of asset pipeline](http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual/#getting-started-2), this is supposed to be the folder structure.

```
Within the grails-app/assets directory are several subfolders
    grails-app/assets/javascripts
    grails-app/assets/stylesheets
    grails-app/assets/images
```

Otherwise, take control

You can include additional folders via ([see here](http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual/#configuration))

```
// in build.gradle
assets {
  includes = ['your/more/js/or/images/folders/etc', 'another/one']
  excludes = ['**/*.less']
}
```

Once you have done that, to refer your resources in gsp files, you need to use

```
<asset:javascript src="app.js"/>
```

#### How do you refer the path to resource in `<asset>` tag.

Say you have a file `grails-app/assets/javascripts/angularjs/app.js` like this in assets folder, then to refer it, you shall do

```
<asset:javascript src="angularjs/app.js"/> // NOTE: assets/javascripts is omitted from the path.
```

Hope this helps.

As a side note, move away from `src/main/webapp` folder. Grails 3 recommend using `src/main/resources/public` (for public resources. static files like htmls etc) and `src/main/resource`.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great explanation. So I think you answered my next question. All my custom `HTML` and `CSS` goes under the `src/main/resources/public` folder right? Do they need to have their respective folders such as `src/main/resources/public/html` and `src/main/resources/public/css`?

Comment: `HTML` should (probably?!) definitely go there. For, CSS (or less) use `grails-app/assets/stylesheets`.

Comment: Ok, and let's say I want to reference a `bootstrap.css` in my static `html` file. Gradle compiled the bootstrap under `grails-app/assets/bower/bootstrap/bootstrap.css`. How would I reference that in my `html`?

Comment: Or any `CSS` file for that matter. If it's under `grails-app/assets/...` then how can I pull that in?

Comment: I don't have definitive answer to that. Never tried myself. But If I were you, I would look the final generated War/Jar and see where are the processed (by asset-pipeline) resources are (I guess they are placed as it is, keeping the directory structure of assets directory) and then try out that path in html. But its just a guess. Do let me know how that turns out. I would like to know answer to that as well. :)

Comment: One needs to use `/static` URL prefix, see https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v3.0.12.